# Print PDF in IE using window.print

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, printing

I have a PDF document that I'm opening in a new window using javascript and then attempting to print using window.print(). The following code works in Chrome, but not IE. Any ideas?

```
var pdfWindow = window.open('/mypdf.pdf', '_blank');
pdfWindow.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

That would probably not work. If you ask me, the best way of implementing PDF in a browser will be to do the following.

Create a PHP file like this: I'm calling this first PHP file "firstfile.php"

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$file='yourpdffile.pdf';
@readfile($file);
?>
```

Then create another PHP file and use iframe to get your desired PDF file. Sample code is below

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/Domainfolder/firstfile.php>" height="400px" width="750px">
  </iframe>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You probably have some bad javascript above that line that only breaks IE. Use developer tools (press F12) in IE to check the console for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this wasn't the case.